# View variable does not get injected in the $scope

Tags: angularjs

The view:

```
<div class="numbers">
    {{calc.amount || 0 }}
</div>
<div class="keypad">
    <div class="number-slot"><button ng-click="numberPressed(1)" class="number">1</button></div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
app.controller('pay-amount', function ($scope, $state, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, ionicMaterialInk) {

    $scope.numberPressed = function (number) {
        console.log(number + " pressed!");
        $scope.calc = {
            amount: "" + $scope.calc.amount + number
        }
    };

    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
});
```

There are no errors till numberPressed(1) is called:

> "ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of
>   undefined".

Upon inspecting $scope, I can't find the "calc" object I defined in the view. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the $scope variable before using it,

```
$scope.calc = {amount:0};
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/MObt2dMa36jkloFOPbuB?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$scope.numberPressed = function (number) {
    console.log(number + " pressed!");
    $scope.calc = {amount:''};
    $scope.calc = {
        amount: "" + $scope.calc.amount + number
    }
    console.log($scope.calc);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `calc` was never set on the `$scope` so it tries to find `amount` on `undefined`

You could make 2 simple changes

```
$scope.calc = {};
$scope.numberPressed = function (number) {
    console.log(number + " pressed!");
    $scope.calc.amount = ($scope.calc.amount || 0) + number
}
```

or

```
$scope.calc = { amount: 0 };
$scope.numberPressed = function (number) {
    console.log(number + " pressed!");
    $scope.calc.amount = $scope.calc.amount + number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$scope.calc = { amount: 0 };
$scope.numberPressed = function (number) {
     console.log(number + " pressed!");
     $scope.calc.amount = $scope.calc.amount + number
}
```